# Create a new matrix from existing matrix between zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have in a matrix data that contains 0 and 'proper' data. I want to crete several matrixes (new ones) to separate the data from the zeros and get rid of these zeros.

So, here is a simple example:

```
data = 1   3   6   4
       3   6   9   5
       4   5   6   2
       0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0
       2   4   1   8
       1   4   6   5
       0   0   0   0
       1   7   9   1
       3   4   5   8
```

And i want to get in this case two matrixes that would be:

```
A =1   3   6   4
   3   6   9   5
   4   5   6   2



B= 2   4   1   8
   1   4   6   5



C = 1   7   9   1
    3   4   5   8
```

Obviously my data files have thousands of datapoint and i need to automat this.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an alternative way that keeps the # of columns of data in the resulted cell array:

```
   L=bwlabel(data);
   for n=1:max(L)
       result{n}=reshape(data(L==n),[],size(data,2));
   end


result = 
[3x4 double]    [2x4 double]    [2x4 double]

result{1}
ans =
         1     3     6     4
         3     6     9     5
         4     5     6     2
```

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: create an index of the rows containing *only zeros* using [all](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html):

```
index = all(data==0,2); #% data==0<-- logical matrix; the 2 means along dimension 2
```

Step 2: create vectors containing the first and last indices of each segment of desired values:

```
index = [1; double(index); 1]; #% convert to numeric and pad with ones
firsts = diff(index)==-1; #% 0 (real row) - 1 (spacer row) = -1
lasts = (diff(index)==1)-1; #% subtract 1 because of padding
```

Step 3: Create a cell array which contains sequential segments of the original matrix in each cell (using [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html), each cell can be a different size, or even a different type):

```
#% firsts and lasts should be the same length
#% iterate through lists of first/last indices
for ii=1:length(firsts)
    result{ii} = data(firsts(ii):lasts(ii), :);
end
```

---

Obligatory Matlab public service announcement: `i` and `j` are popular loop index variables... you'll notice I used `ii` instead.  [Here's why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)